# How to navigate without context in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I have an app that recieves push notification using OneSignal. I have made a notification opened handler that should open specific screen on click of the notification. How can i navigate to a screen without context. or how can I open specific screen on app startup. My code:

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((notification) {
  var notify = notification.notification.payload.additionalData;
  if (notify["type"] == "message") {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DM(user: notify['id']),
      ),
    );
  }
  if (notify["type"] == "user") {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Profileo(notify["id"]),
      ),
    );
  }
  if (notify["type"] == "post") {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ViewPost(notify["id"]),
      ),
    );
  }
});
```

I am able to achieve this when the app is opened for the first time but It only opens the homepage If i close the app and even if I re-open it. I guess that is because the context is changed.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Look at this here:
https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074

You can set a global key for your navigation:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Pass it to MaterialApp:

```
new MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
```

Push routes:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/someRoute');
```

Comment: navigatorKey is undefined

Comment: @temirbek define navigatorKey in your main.dart and import it in your other file.

Comment: in addition, set the *navigatorKey* property of the MaterialApp to the declared global key (navigatorKey), not the *key* property of MaterialApp

Comment: @Mustafa can you please provide sample? I have read many blogs and forums all are giving same solutions but navigator key is accessible from my dio interceptor.

Comment: how can we pass multiple parameters? kindly suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh create a custom class, and pass that class as an argument

Comment: We are using go router to define the names routes. Will this still work?

Comment: How to pass variables at the time of pushing to new routes? passing data to the class parameter with context seems different from this.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have been stuck for some time now trying to figure a way around managing navigation in an environment that employs both Nav 2.0 and Nav 1.0. This approach helped me figure a solution to my problem. Thanks a million time. I wish there was a super upvote to give it to you.

Comment: Is there any drawback to use this approach more frequently?

Comment: It's great, but if you want to restart the app by resetting the key (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50116077/9885611), this method will not work.

Comment: Similar to the question by @Satchel: Does this method interoperate with `Navigator.of(context).pop()` etc.? Or does this create a second `NavigatorState`? Does this then break libraries that directly call `Navigator.of(context)`?

Answer (score 27):

You can use this wonderful plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/get

Description from the package: A consistent navigation library that lets you navigate between screens, open dialogs, and display snackbars from anywhere in your code without context.

```
Get.to(NextScreen()); // look at this simplicity :)
Get.back(); //  pop()
Get.off(NextScreen()); // clears the previous routes and opens a new screen.
```

Comment: Downvote because importing GetX to solve a problem with navigation is overkill.

Comment: This package is definitely NOT wonderful. It has numerous bugs, code stolen from other libraries, and abandoned by its creator.

Answer (score 11):

Quickest fix is above using global `navigatorKey` (like @tsdevelopment answered).
To fix undefined `navigatorKey`, it must be imported from where it is instantiated (for this example in `main.dart`).

Your `main.dart`

```dart
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(CupertinoApp(
    title: 'Navigate without context',
    initialRoute: '/',
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // important
    onGenerateRoute: ...
  ));
}
```

For example you are in your `lib/utils/api.dart`

```dart
import 'package:your_package_name/main.dart'; // important

abstract class API {
  static Future<dynamic> get() async {
     // call some api
     ...
     // then you want to navigate to specific screen like login
     navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/login'); // navigate to login, with null-aware check
  }
}
```

Also have a gist example if you prefer in a service approach.
Check this: https://gist.github.com/josephdicdican/81e59fad70530eac251ad6c28e2dcd4b

Answer (score 7):

This solution is general if you want to navigate or to show dialog without context using globalKey especially with Bloc or when your logic is separated from your UI part.

Firstly install this package:

Not: I'm using null safety version

```
  get_it: ^7.2.0
```

Then create a separate file for your service locator:

**service_location.dart**

```
    import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
    
    GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
    
    class NavigationService {
      final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
          new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
      Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
        return navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeName);
      }
    
      void setupLocator() {
        locator.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
      }

  void showMyDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        builder: (context) => Center(
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ));
  }
    }
```

on **main.dart:**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NavigationService().setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
// add navigatorKey for MaterialApp

 MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
      ),
```

at your business logic file **bloc.dart**
define this inside the bloc class or at whatever class you want to use  navigation inside
Then start to navigate inside any function inside.

```
class Cubit extends Cubit<CubitState> {
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
  void sampleFunction(){
       _navigationService.navigateTo('/home_screen'); // to navigate
       _navigationService.showMyDialog(); // to show dialog

    }
}
```

Not: I'm using generateRoute for routing.

Comment: get_it isn't getx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [no_context_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/no_context_navigation)  package

as the name suggests, we can navigate without context

```
navService.pushNamed('/detail_screen', args: 'From Home Screen');
```

Comment: It is not a plugin, because it contains no native bridge.

Comment: You right its a package

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but there is a package that handles navigation without the build context (Using a navigator key) called flutter_navigator: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_navigator

It allows you to navigate something like this:

```
_flutterNavigation.push(//YourRoute);
```

Everything seems to be mapped 1:1 with Flutter's Navigator API, so there is no worries there!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine. I just wanted to add if anyone wants to do `pushReplacement` without `context`. In that case this can help

```
navigatorKey.getCurrentState()?.pushNamed(
        '/someRoute',
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        navigatorKey.getCurrentState()?.pushReplacement(value as Route<Object>);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deep_route](https://pub.dev/packages/deep_route) navigation package. This will help us navigate any page from anywhere within the code even from the business logic. It doesn't require any context.

Replace MaterialApp with

```
void main() => runApp(DeepMaterialApp(home: Home()));
```

Navigate using

```
DeepRoute.toNamed('/RouteName', arguments: 'sample');
DeepRoute.to(NextPage());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually pass the context outside the builder(), by adding parameter value to the method.

for example, if you need to use navigator push in dart file without builder.

you can do this

```
methodName(String name, String address, context){
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
}
```

Comment: He is asking **How to navigate without context** . Your answer is another way of navigating but it still uses context.

Comment: Works for me. I didn't know there's a way of using context like this for navigation. Thanks a lot :)