# Why does flutter dio interceptor not invoking the method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am working on a flutter application which uses JWT to access backend endpoints.
When the access token expires, I added an interceptor to refresh the token based on the solutions provided here:
[Using Interceptor in Dio for Flutter to Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740793/using-interceptor-in-dio-for-flutter-to-refresh-token)
I could see server logs which says 401.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:dummy/utils/config.dart';

Future<Response> uploadVideo(filePath, fileName, title, jwt) async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  var token = json.decode(jwt);
  dio.interceptors.clear();

  dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${token['access']}";
  dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onError: (error) async {
    print(error.response);
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 403 ||
     error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
    await refreshToken(jwt);
    _retry(error.request, dio);
     }
    return error.response;
  }));
  Response response;
  try {
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file_name": fileName,
      "content": await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath),
      'title': title,
    });
    response = await dio.post("$BASE_URL/video/create/", data: formData);
    return response;
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    if (e.response) {
      print(e.response.data);
      print(e.response.headers);
      print(e.response.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
      print(e.request);
      print(e.message);
    }
    return e.response;
  }
}

Future<Response<dynamic>> _retry(RequestOptions requestOptions, Dio dio) async {
  final options = new Options(
    method: requestOptions.method,
    headers: requestOptions.headers,
  );
  return dio.request<dynamic>(requestOptions.path,
      data: requestOptions.data,
      queryParameters: requestOptions.queryParameters,
      options: options);
}

Future<Response> refreshToken(jwt) async {
  print("COMING INSIDE");
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  var token = json.decode(jwt);
  var refreshToken = token['refresh'];
  Response response;
  try {
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "refresh": refreshToken,
    });
    response = await dio.post("$BASE_URL/auth/login/refresh/", data: formData);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    return e.response;
  }
}
```

I tried with debugger as well, but its not executing the code after if statement where it checks for 401 and 403. Server clearly gives 401 as I am running it locally so I can see the logs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide an output example of `print(error.response);`?

Comment: Hi, I am getting this ` DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = 172.22.22.55, port = 47164.response
`

Comment: I could confirm the app reaches the backend server, have login and register screens which works fine.

Comment: Did this happen with the upgrade to dio 4?

Comment: @Anoop.P.AI didnt upgrade to dio 4, am on 3.0.10, is there a 4 version? I thought the latest is 3.0.10

Comment: Is there any restriction on the file size on the server side? Check [this](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/492#issuecomment-546660005)

Comment: Nope, the same endpoint was working fine with sending files before JWT restriction was applied.

Comment: As I said earlier as well, I could see my server logs, it says 401

Comment: could you please print out more things and show it in your question. e.g. print out `error.response?.statusCode` in your onError.

Comment: `error.response?.statusCode` is not printing ..its null as error.response is not there

Comment: @Maverick could you please give a minimal reproducible sample, then I can debug on it. p.s. please "@ch271828n" otherwise I cannot see your reply

Comment: @Maverick maybe you have a problem with the refresh token itself ?

Comment: based on your `print(error.response);` output I think it could be an endpoint issue check [this link](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/492). I think you need to hadle `if(e.error is SocketException)` case also.

Comment: You are getting a DioErrorType.DEFAULT which has no response and thus also no status code. Only DioErrorType.RESPONSE has a response attached. This also means your error probably has nothing to with the refresh token or the server response. You are likely seeing some problem due to TLS, proxy, connection abort, whatever. Something in between the server and Dio.

Comment: Hi @kuhnroyal I could see the logs on the server end, request is reaching there.

Comment: No doubt there but the response is not coming back. The socket is being closed before the response can be read, write timeout, whatever. `SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32` is your problem. You need to investigate there, I don't think anyone here can help you.

Comment: @Maverick print the error object in the first line of your error callback to check which existing DioError types are occurring the error.response exists only if the error type is DioErrorType.response if other error types are happing for example DioErrorType.connectTimeout or DioErrorType.other those have their own problem and they are not related to the status code  of the response

Comment: @Maverick if your token is based on jwt, you can check token is expired or not with jwt_decoder package instead of adding interceptor

Comment: I face kinda the same thing in dio 3.0.10. Have tried dio 4.0.0?

Comment: @Nux did it work for you in 4.0.0? Havent tried it yet.

Comment: No I haven't but I guess it may work. For your auth flow this issue may offer some help https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/590

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your Interceptor:

```dart
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onError: (error) async {
    print(error.response);
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 403 ||
     error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
    await refreshToken(jwt);
    _retry(error.request, dio);
     }
    return error.response;
  }));
```

You're calling retry method, but:

- you don't wait for result;
- you return an error anyway.

Try to add `return` before `_retry` instead:

```dart
dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(onError: (error) async {
    print(error.response);
    if (error.response?.statusCode == 403 ||
     error.response?.statusCode == 401) {
    await refreshToken(jwt);
    return _retry(error.request, dio);
     }
    return error.response;
  }));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I would think this could be the case if the execution reaches that if block, but it doest as statuscode is not present.