# Redirect menuitem to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have this function that creates the menu item but it has no functionality, i want is so that i can send it to what page i want when declaring it. How can i do this?

```
final List<MenuItem> options = [
MenuItem(Icons.home, 'Home'),
MenuItem(Icons.person, 'Profile'),
MenuItem(Icons.web_asset, 'Website'),
MenuItem(Icons.settings, 'Settings'),
```

];

```
             children: options.map((item) {
            
            return ListTile(
              
              onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HERE I WANT TO PUT A CUSTOM PAGE FOR EACH ONE()),
                );
          },
              leading: Icon(
                item.icon,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 35,
              ),
              title: Text(
                item.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          }).to
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Function OnTap; to your model like below :

```
class MenuItem{
  Icon icon;
  String title;
  Function OnTap;

  MenuItem(this.icon, this.title, this.OnTap);
}
```

and next add new objects;

```
final List<MenuItem> options = [
MenuItem(Icons.home, 'Home',(){print("define_onclick_here");}),
MenuItem(Icons.person, 'Profile',(){print("define_onclick_here");}),
MenuItem(Icons.web_asset, 'Website',(){print("define_onclick_here");}),
MenuItem(Icons.settings, 'Settings',(){print("define_onclick_here");}),];
```

and finally add `item.OnTap();` in list item onTap:

```
  children: options.map((item) {
        
        return ListTile(
          
          onTap: () {
        item.OnTap();
      },
          leading: Icon(
            item.icon,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 35,
          ),
          title: Text(
            item.title,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      }).to
```

Comment: one thing. I add this to the define_onclick_here ("""Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()),
                    );""") and nothing happens. What should i add there?

Comment: @AndreiMarin use

(){
  Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()));
}

Comment: Do you have any idea why i get the error 'unidentified name context' ? https://gyazo.com/ff7c46856e2bf15b7d60910dccfb2e87

Comment: @AndreiMarin may be you don't access context in this file, please read below page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962112/how-to-navigate-without-context-in-flutter-app