# List of String to List of StatefulWidget Flutter

Tags: flutter, navbar, stateful

I want to convert this list string to list stateful widget

```
List<String> listString = [
"HomePage()",
"ProfilePage()"
]
```

to

```
List<StatefulWidget> listStatefulWidget = [];
```

expected result :

```
List<StatefulWidget> listStatefulWidget = [
HomePage(),
ProfilePage()
];
```

update :
I need this for my navbar that require a list of StatefulWidget. `tabs` is list of StatefulWidget thats should be get the value from API. my API return listString, so I need to convert it to statefulWidget.

here my code:

```
var tabs<StatefulWidget> = [
    HomePageView() 
    AccountView(),
  ];

return Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
      key: _bottomNavigationKey,
      index: 0,
      height: 65.0,
      items: [
       //navbar 
      ],
      color: Colors.white,
      buttonBackgroundColor: kSecondaryColor,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutQuint,
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      onTap: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _page = index;
        });
      },
      letIndexChange: (index) => true,
    ),
    body: tabs[_page]);
```

}

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @NishuthanS shortly I got list of string from API (ex: "HomePage()"). then I want to convert it to StatefulWidget that uses for Navigate to each class in Bottom Navigation Bar

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a `String` to a `StatefulWidget`.

What you can do is use the string with `NavigatorState` to navigate to parts of the app.

**Global key for NavigatorState**

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
      switch (routeSettings.name) { //add more routes as needed
        case 'Home':
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home());
        default:
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile());
      }
    },
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

**Navigating to the page**

You can use this `navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(<Route Name>)` to navigate to the page.

Example : `navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('Home')` This will navigate you to `Home` page.

In your case, you can get the routes from an API and build a bottom Navigation bar and use the string to navigate to pages.

Example:

`navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(listStatefulWidget [index]);`

**Refer:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53397266/9074190

https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr. @Nisuthan S, appreciate it. What I wanted is listofStatelesWidget from String coz navigation bar required list of statefulwidget. I have updated my question. If you dont mind, can you check it please? Thank you.