# while clicking local push notification how to navigate and reload a page in flutter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flutter

i am new in flutter app. i have used flutter local push notification as the following [example link](https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-local-notifications-in-flutter/), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLBWAA14hf4). it's working fine but while clicking the notification the page doesn't navigate and reload.

how to navigate and reload the page while clicking the notification?

I have also created second screen (this is navigate page) but in this code selectNotification functionality not working.

```
//notification_service.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'secondscreen.dart';

import 'main.dart';

class NotificationService {
  //NotificationService a singleton object
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();

  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  NotificationService._internal();

  static const channelId = '123';

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> init() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
            macOS: null);

    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
  }

  AndroidNotificationDetails _androidNotificationDetails =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel ID',
    'channel name',
    'channel description',
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.high,
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  Future<void> showNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      "Notification sundar",
      "This is the Notification Body!",
      NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        "Notification Title",
        "This is the Notification Body!",
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
        NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotifications(int id) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  Future<void> cancelAllNotifications() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }
}

Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
  //handle your logic here
  print('String');
  if (payload != null) {
    print('sundar');
    BuildContext context;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );
  }
}

//main.dart
import 'secondscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tasker/notification_service.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().init();
  // NotificationService().requestIOSPermissions(); //
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          accentColor: Colors.indigo.shade900,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.indigo.shade900)),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Local Notifications'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  NotificationService _notificationService = NotificationService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Show Notification'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _notificationService.showNotifications();
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Schedule Notification'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _notificationService.scheduleNotifications();
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Cancel Notification'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _notificationService.cancelNotifications(0);
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Cancel All Notifications'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _notificationService.cancelAllNotifications();
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  SizedBox(height: 3),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('naviagte page'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                      // );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you provide a `BuildContext`  in `selectNotification` to route? Actually here `BuildContext context;` is null and you can not use that.
Here, your `BuildContext` is null and is not your app context. So you should use no-context  routing such as https://pub.dev/packages/no_context_navigation. Also you can see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962112/how-to-navigate-without-context-in-flutter-app

Comment: hi bro i tryed but not working pls help me(sampel link: https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-local-notifications-in-flutter/)
Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload)),
    );
}

Answer (score 2):

As an easy way, use the `navigator key`. You can read more at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/no_context_navigation).

first define `NavigationService` class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final NavigationService navService = NavigationService();

class NavigationService<T, U> {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<T> pushNamed(String routeName, {Object args}) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.pushNamed<T>(
        routeName,
        arguments: args,
      );

  Future<T> push(Route<T> route) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.push<T>(route);

  Future<T> pushReplacementNamed(String routeName, {Object args}) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed<T, U>(
        routeName,
        arguments: args,
      );

  Future<T> pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
    String routeName, {
    Object args,
    bool keepPreviousPages = false,
  }) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<T>(
        routeName,
        (Route<dynamic> route) => keepPreviousPages,
        arguments: args,
      );

  Future<T> pushAndRemoveUntil(
    Route<T> route, {
    bool keepPreviousPages = false,
  }) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil<T>(
        route,
        (Route<dynamic> route) => keepPreviousPages,
      );

  Future<bool> maybePop([Object args]) async =>
      navigationKey.currentState.maybePop<bool>(args);

  bool canPop() => navigationKey.currentState.canPop();

  void goBack({T result}) => navigationKey.currentState.pop<T>(result);
}
```

Here you can define your routes

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigationKey,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          accentColor: Colors.indigo.shade900,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.indigo.shade900)),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage());
          case '/second_screen':
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondScreen(settings.arguments)
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  NotificationService _notificationService = NotificationService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal:10),
          child: Center(
          child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //your child
          ],
        ),
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

and in the `NotificationService`

```
Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
  //handle your logic here
  print('String');
  if (payload != null) {
    navService.pushNamed('/detail_screen', args: payload);;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank u bro working fine, but not reloading or page refresh. i need naviagate with reload hole page pls help.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, but when you call `navService.pushNamed('/detail_screen', args: payload);` this navigate to new `DetailScreen`. If you want to reload the previous screen, you should use appropriate structure, like `Bloc`. Then, you are able to reload after Navigation. `Push` and `PushNamed` are Future, so, you can use await. As I said, you have to use good architecture to reach this.

Comment: Bro, could you pls provide sample code for reloading current active page

Comment: While clicking notifications navigate detail page still this working fine. But what i need is after coming to this screen the page should refresh. Each and every time while clicking notification the page should refresh.