# video call acceptance screen with Agora flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, agora.io

I'm trying to build a video calling app with [Agora](https://agora.io), I need to show acceptance screen like WhatsApp when user calling, if the app is exited i need to show calling screen when user is calling, I tried lot of thing but nothing works, I trying to do i flutter and but there is nothing much information on this,Please help me

Comment: You may start searching for concepts like "How to start activities from the background". From what I could understand in the question, the problem might be about restrictions doing that (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

I recommend you explaining more and adding code in your question:
AndroidManifest.xml permissions, Activities used, the foreground Service you may have to be running, etc.

Comment: i have tried several codes,nothig seems to work,i need to everything in flutter,the app is also for ios,i need something universal,so that  i don't have write everything in native @DNax

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Comment: starting an activity from service, when screen is locked and or app is terminated /background

Comment: I've developed a voip app. For ios we use callkit but for android we issue a notification for an incoming call. The user clicks on the notification launching the app. This paradigm then works whether the screen is turned off or locked.

Comment: @spartygw what about popular video calling apps which show incoming call screen even if screen is locked

Comment: @joyBlanks apple makes this easy with CallKit. Android less so. I know Samsung has their own thing but I haven't yet figured out a similar thing in Android that works across all flavors so we go with the notification paradigm I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First things first. You need to learn about some concepts before delving into your solution. Actually there isn't an out of the box solution.

You need to use a couple of things together:

- Use push notifications to "wake up" your app:

     https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

   To start your app using push notifications refers to this post:

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405551/4335775
- Use CallKit (IOS) or ConnectionServices (Android) to show the upcoming call screen. By the day of this answer there are only a few packages to handle these things, here is one that can handle both platforms:

   https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkeep

If you want a completely different thing and need to run some background process, there are bunch whole of things you should know first. 
I suggest beginning here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

 
Here is a usefull package to work with background processes that should be constantly running:

 https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Currently there are two packages which provides integration for agora.io:

- https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine (for Agora Real Time Communication, vídeo call included)
- https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm for real-time messaging

I hope this can help you.

Comment: hi will you provide some code of this.

Comment: We have implemented the CallKeep package for Agora: https://github.com/Clinica-Mongolia/callkeep_agora

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WorkManager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) plugin.

You can register an call back function to the os when the app is closed.

```
const myTask = "syncWithTheBackEnd";

void main() {
  Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  Workmanager.registerOneOffTask(
    "1",
    myTask, //This is the value that will be returned in the callbackDispatcher
    initialDelay: Duration(minutes: 5),
    constraints: WorkManagerConstraintConfig(
      requiresCharging: true,
      networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task) {
    switch (task) {
      case myTask:
        print("this method was called from native!");
        break;
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        break;
    }

    //Return true when the task executed successfully or not
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Maybe this can help you.

The complete article [medium article](https://medium.com/vrt-digital-studio/flutter-workmanager-81e0cfbd6f6e)

Comment: looking for a fullscreen activity like incoming call screen when app is terminated/inbackground and screen may or mayn't be locked