# I just want to show an incoming ui call screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show The incoming call ui screen in flutter. Please help someone how can I do it.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLKKi.png). please someone help how can I do this...

Comment: How do you implement this? Actually, I need to display my custom incoming and outgoing call screens instead of the default call screens. Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming). Documentation is pretty straightforward so you can take a look at that.

Comment: do I need to write native codes in this package..

Comment: Nope, its a flutter package.

Comment: is it difficult to do this?

Comment: I donot want to integrate call system in it . I just want to show the screen to the other mobile from click by another mobile. with default or custom sound. will this help me?

Comment: You can read the documentation, it requires your backend server to send the push notification to the receiver.

Comment: can we use this even when app terminates fully or is it only for when device is active

Comment: Push notifications can be sent to offline devices too.

Comment: so it means it can work in background or when app is terminated also.

Comment: Correct, yes right

Comment: One last question sir. Will this work fine for ios also? And also will the action button work fine in the background also because the action button didnt work in the background for me. Please answer this two question. I am confused. And thank you sir for this much help.

Comment: I have used it myself, it works perfectly, but remember this only helps popping up the native and flutter incoming screens whenever there is a push notification from your backend server.

Comment: Is firebase perfect for that? And also please say will that work fine for ios also? Thank you very much sirrr...

Comment: Yes it will work, and firebase cloud messaging be a good choice.

Comment: one last time sir. please dont be annoyed, I am intermediate so little confusion. This surely works for multiple devices right sir, or only for only one device.

Comment: hello sir. My action button didn't work please suggest me some method. I used on background method but it didn't work. The action button worked fine in foreground and when app is in open state but the button is not working in background..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer `connectycube_flutter_call_kit` package  [here](https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_flutter_call_kit) or`flutter_callkit_incoming` package  [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) or also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509151/13997210) answer for that

Comment: do I need to write any native code in this package.