# How to open my app from background and navigate to a page on receiving a notification message in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-application

I need to open the app automatically on receiving a notification message. Is it possible in flutter?

Below is the code for handling the background messages and it works.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  ......
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp()
    )
  );
```

What I need is I have a separate page that needs to popup when that particular function is executed (When the app is in background). Can anyone help me out with this! Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: From what I have researched, android does not allow apps to automatically open without any user interaction. If you have the latest android u would notice, even phone calls only pop a notification, and only when clicked the app opens.

Comment: When user click the notification that's possible to take user to a specific screen when application is terminated ? I am using firebase_messaging: ^10.0.8 .

Comment: I that case this answer would help you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48405551/12131806

Comment: Thank you . But in this answer link they are using old version of firebase_messaging.

Comment: Yeah but you can use that GlobalKey method in that background handler function. That will work

Comment: yes. I use that  `final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); ` but did not work when user click on the notification just Application open not take the user to specific screen.
`   navigatorKey.currentState.push(PageRouteBuilder(
                    opaque: false,
                    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => ProfilePage(
                      userId: int.parse(message.data["userId"].toString()),
                    ),
                  )); `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237688/discussion-between-wahab-sohail-and-nagulan-s).

Answer (score 0):

```
    await _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('topic name');
    _firebaseMessaging.configure
    (
        
        // The onMessage function triggers when the notification is 
        received while we are running the app.
        onMessage: (message) async
        {
            setState(()
            {
                messageTitle = message["notification"]["title"];
                messageDescription = message["notification"]["description"];
                notificationAlert = "New Notification Alert";
            });

        },
        // The onResume function triggers when we receive the notification alert in the device notification bar and opens the app through the push notification itself. In this case, the app can be running in the background or not running at all.
        onResume: (message) async
        {
            print("ON RESUME");

            setState(() 
            {
                messageTitle = message["data"]["title"];
                messageDescription = message["notification"]["description"];
                notificationAlert = "Application opened from Notification";
            });
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async // Called when app is terminated
        {
            print("onLaunch: $message");

            var data = message["data"];

            print(data);

            // Navigator.pushNamed(context, "details");
        }
    );
```

In this code the **onResume** function will help you run the app from background so you can code inside onResume and navigate to your specified screen.

Comment: If I am not wrong this is for the older version of firebase messaging. In the current version, the background message function does that part, but the difference is background message is done outside void main so the app is not opening.