# FCM push notification payload

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

i have this payload below that send push from firebase function. the payload send notification successful to Android. now i am confused about the iOS.

my Question is that:

will this also send to iOs because i can see that there is no alert in the payload in apsn.
i fellow the documentation in this [site](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/server-integration) which they did not give ios payload.
when i make a research on iOs payload i can see something like this

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

but in the documentation i cant found where they give alert

```
exports.chatFunctions = functions.firestore.document("chat/{chatId}/Messages/{messagesId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        console.log('No Device');
    }
    const chatDatas = snapshot.data();
    const messageTo = chatDatas['idTo'];
    const deviceTokenuUser1 = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(messageTo).get();
    const user1name = deviceTokenuUser1.data()['name'];
    const user1Url = deviceTokenuUser1.data()['profilePictureUrl'];

    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: `${user1name}`,
            body: `${chatDatas['content']}`,
        },
        data: {
            key: 'chat',
            id: `${messageTo}`,
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
        },
        android: {
            priority: "high",
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    contentAvailable: true,
                },
            },
            headers: {
                "apns-push-type": "background",
                "apns-priority": "5", // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
                "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
            },
        },

        token: deviceTokenuUser1.data()['tokens'],
    };
    try {
        await admin.messaging().send(payload);

        console.log("Firebase chat Messaging Successfully");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error from chat messaging " + err);
}
```