# Navigate to another screen when I click on Firebase push notification either in foreground or background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase messaging in my Flutter app , I want to navigate to another screen when I click on the notification even my app is in foreground or background , I used many functions and it doesn't trigger the click event and I can't find anything can solve my problem  .

When I click on the notification when app is in foreground or background , nothing happened because it navigate to the same page .
And when I click on the notification when app is terminated , it opens on Splash screen and go to the home not the screen that I want .

I added this `intent-filter` in my `Manifest`

```
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

And I added this to the `Json` object

```
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
```

And here is how can I get background FCM in the `main.dart`

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //final sound = 'sound.mp3';
  print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');

  final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  final ios = IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestSoundPermission: false,
    requestBadgePermission: false,
    requestAlertPermission: false,);
  final settings = InitializationSettings(android: android,iOS: ios);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(settings,);
  if(message.data['title'].toString().toLowerCase()=="new request") {
    sessionManager.getBadge().then((badge) {
      if (badge != null) {
        int x = badge + 1;
        sessionManager.saveBadge(x);
        print("notification number is " + x.toString());
      }
      else {
        sessionManager.saveBadge(1);
      }
    });

  }

  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      message.data.hashCode,
      message.data['title'],
      message.data['body'],
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          importance: Importance.high,
          priority: Priority.high,
         // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound.split('.').first),
          playSound: true,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        ),

      ));
  /*NotificationApi.showNotification(
      title: message.data['title'],
      body: message.data['body'],
      payload: "",
      id:  int.parse(channel.id));*/

}


Future<void>  main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,

  );
  


  runApp(MyApps());
  // configLoading();

}


class MyApps extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApps({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyApp();
  }
}


class MyApp extends State<MyApps> {
  static  ValueNotifier<int> strikeNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);

  Color _primaryColor =  Color(0xff0d8b75);


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
      designSize: const Size(1080, 2280),
    );
  }


  void showNotification(String title, String body) async {
    await _demoNotification(title, body);
  }

  Future<void> _demoNotification(String title, String body) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel_I', 'channel name',
        showProgress: true,
        priority: Priority.high,
        playSound: true,
        ticker: 'test ticker');

    var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'test');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

       FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
  if (message != null) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DoneAndPaiedPagess(0)));

  }
});

    getToken().then((value) {
      if(value!=null) {
        AppConstants.firebaseToken = value;
      }
    });


    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =  AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS =  IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings =  InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      );



    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      var data = message.data;
      //  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;/


      if (data != null ) {
        if(data['title'].toString().toLowerCase()=="new request") {
          SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager(context);
          sessionManager.getBadge().then((badge) {
            if (badge != null) {
              setState(() {
                int x = badge + 1;
                strikeNotifier.value = x;
                sessionManager.saveBadge(x);
              });
            }
            else {
              strikeNotifier.value = 1;
              sessionManager.saveBadge(1);
            }
          });
        }
        print("entered");
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            data.hashCode,
            data['title'],
            data['body'],
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));

      }
    });
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DoneAndPaiedPagess(0)));

});
   
  }

  Future<String?> getToken() async{
    String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    print("token is "+token!);
    return token;

  }
}
```

In `yaml`

```
 firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.1.6
```

Edit : from multiple solutions , I tried the most common solution that I used `onMessageOpenedApp` in `initState` but it doesn't enter in it

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DoneAndPaiedPagess(0)));
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, you are using the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin and you are creating local notification when you get a push notification from firebase messaging.

Since the notification is not created by firebase messaging so, you are not getting on tap callback in `getInitialMessage` and `onMessageOpenedApp`.

In order to get on tap callback on local notifications, you can pass a callback function while initializing `flutter_local_notifications`

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

void selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
// Here you can check notification payload and redirect user to the respective screen
      await Navigator.push(
         context,
         MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload)),
      );
    }
}
```

For more, you can check `flutter_local_notifications` documentation

Comment: It worked when app is in foreground and background . Do you know how I make it work when app is closed ?

Comment: In FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() , message always return null

Comment: For terminated state you have to use getNotificationAppLaunchDetails() 
Check this: https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1594

Comment: I will check it but I have faced another problem suddenly notifications don't come even in foreground or background , I'm trying to solve it

Answer (score 3):

On your home widget within initState, check the `getInitialMessage` value :

```
// get the remote message when your app opened from push notification while in background state
RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

// check if it is exists
if (initialMessage != null) {
    // check the data property within RemoteMessage and do navigate based on it
}
```

Check the firebase flutter documentation here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#handling-interaction.

Comment: I tried it before but I will check it again

Comment: When I click on the notification , it doesn't enter in setupInteractedMessage() function

Comment: `getInitialMessage` will return a `RemoteMessage `, only if the application is opened from a terminated state. Once consumed, the `RemoteMessage` will be removed.

Comment: I closed my app and re-opened it from the notification , it didn't go to the specific page , it is opened on Splash then home screen and not to the specific screen

Comment: Do you know why all these solutions don't work ?

Comment: Almost all of my Flutter app project that use Firebase as push notification service for both Android and iOS, just copy-paste code from the documentation then adding some business logic into it. Sometimes it's not working because I put it in the wrong place. You need to see firebase example [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib).

Comment: exactly , Ok I will check it

Comment: unfortunately , this code is just for get notifications not make a click on it

Comment: What do you mean? From the [main.dart#L157](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart#L157) you can listen to  `onMessageOpenedApp` stream that is called when a user presses a notification message displayed via FCM. Just read the documentation  https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html

Comment: Please look at the edit in the ``main`` in my code .. I added onMessageOpenedApp and initialMessage but also it didn't navigate to the other page eight in foreground or background

Comment: Add some `print` code before push a navigation. Is there any error occurred while tapping the notification?

Comment: I added print lines but it is not enter in onMessageOpenedApp or check of the  initialMessage

Answer (score 2):

Use [onMessageOpenedApp](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onMessageOpenedApp.html) stream to listen when a notification is opened in the foreground or background. When the application is terminated, use [getInitialMessage](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getInitialMessage.html) to get a pending notification.

Comment: I already get the notification when app is terminated , I want to make a click listener on it

Comment: I used onMessageOpenedApp before and it didn't work . I used it in`` Init`` function like this 



    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const login()));

    });

Answer (score 1):

I am no sure if this helps right now. But as explained  [Firebase Messaging docs handling-interaction](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#handling-interaction) and the actual firebase messaging example in [github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart)  You should use `onMessageOpenedApp` A Stream which posts a `RemoteMessage` when the application is opened from a background state. and `getInitialMessage` If the application is opened from a terminated state a `Future` containing a `RemoteMessage` will be returned.

You should follow the code written on the GitHub example and implement it on your own way. I hope this helps.