# The backgroundHandler needs to be either a static function or a top level function to be accessible as a Flutter entry point

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-local-notification

hey guys when I use onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse in [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) I got an error can someone help me?

[here is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VUA9.png)

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMnPI.png)

actually  I want navigate to second page after user select my notification in background mode but I got this problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the definition of function used as backgroundHandler outside of any class.

For example:

```
// If in main.dart
main() {
  // ...
}

ClassABC {
  void getLetter() => print('a and b');
}

// Notice how this is outside of classABC scope and main scope.
backgroundHandler() {
  // Put handling code here.
}
```

For more clarity, could you post the whole page code?

Comment: can you please explain how it works with details, and where backgroundHandler call. also in backgroundhandler i want to navigate to specific screen so how it is possible

Comment: main() {
/* callback is set to the NotificationService (Firebase or whatever) via the registerCallback method( just named it so, check out the code i link below for proper method name in case of Firebase) */
  NotificationService.registerCallback(backgroundHandler);
}

ClassABC {
  void getLetter() => print('a and b');
}

// Notice how this is outside of classABC scope and main scope.
backgroundHandler() {
  // Put handling code here.
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403786/how-to-open-particular-screen-on-clicking-on-push-notification-for-flutter

Comment: You need to use a global Scaffold key in order to navigate to specific page since no context is available... follow the link for code and more info !

Answer (score 0):

> actually I want navigate to second page after user select my notification in background mode but I got this problem

Answering on how to navigate from a Top Level Function:

I made a Singleton which is accesible from Top Level Function. This singleton manages a Stream and emits a new event everytime the user taps on a notification.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:listsapp/common/types/types.dart';

class ActionNotificationService {
  factory ActionNotificationService() => _instance ??= ActionNotificationService._();

  ActionNotificationService._() : _notificationsController = StreamController.broadcast();

  static ActionNotificationService? _instance;
  final StreamController<JSON> _notificationsController;

  void add(JSON payload) => _notificationsController.add(payload);

  Stream<JSON> getNotificationOpenedStream() => _notificationsController.stream;

  void close() {
    _notificationsController.close();
  }
}
```

Inside my app I listen to this stream and navigate to the specific screen.

Also, remember to close the singleton stream when your application doesn't need it no more.