# What do I use for context when directing the user to a specific page on notification click?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following this answer to handle what happens when a user clicks on a notification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74288639/4838216

When the user clicks my basic notification, I want it to take them to the notifications page. However, using `Navigator.push(...` requires a `BuildContext`. I don't think I have one in this case because this is a helper class called `FirebaseHelper`. How do I get the context to use here? Or is there another way to do this?

```
//This method will call when the app is in background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        //Handle push notification redirection here
        print('##MyApp## _setUpNotificationListener onMessageOpenedApp.listen');
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenNotifications()),);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little bit cumbersome when using default flutter navigation ,because it deals with context , So I suggest you to use Getx package which has many functionalities need of context to navigate. Speed up the dev process.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

```
Get.to(NextScreen());
ex: Get.to(ScreenNotifications())
```

just move you to next page.
see more on the documentation.

```
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        //Handle push notification redirection here
        print('##MyApp## _setUpNotificationListener onMessageOpenedApp.listen');
        Get.to(ScreenNotifications());
      }
    });
```

Comment: Is this a reliable package to use?

Comment: Yh,of course,see flutter documentation it is a recommended package

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#getx